# Htaccess file force HTTPS is redirecting my subpages to the homepage

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get my website to redirect to HTTPS. I got it working on one of my websites. But on my 2nd one I am getting issues (this is a Wordpress site).

I am using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pazio.nl/$1 [R,L]
```

But now, when I try to browse to http://www.pazio.nl/subpage it redirects me to to https://www.pazio.nl/ instead of the HTTPS version of the subpage. I have been searching the web all day and have failed to find the answer.

I hope someone here can help me.